# math operator difference *= or +=

Tags: python, pytorch

I found a weird thing when I used the operator e.g. `*=` or `+=`

The code:

```
aa = Variable(torch.FloatTensor([[1,2],[3,4]]))
bb = aa
bb = bb*2
print(bb)
print(aa)

cc = Variable(torch.FloatTensor([[1,2],[3,4]]))
dd = cc
dd *= 2
print(cc)
print(dd)
```

The results showed as below:

```
Variable containing:
 2  4
 6  8
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2]

Variable containing:
 1  2
 3  4
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2]

Variable containing:
 2  4
 6  8
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2]

Variable containing:
 2  4
 6  8
[torch.FloatTensor of size 2x2]
```

As you see, when I used `bb=bb*2`, `aa` was not be affected. However, if using `dd *= 2`, `cc` seems to point towards (share) the same address as `cc`, it is changed.

Their respective previous line is the same, e.g. `bb = aa` and `dd = cc`. It seems that the `*=` operator changed the original deep copy to shallow copy and the change was made after the copy line itself.

I am wondering if this is a bug. If it is, it is important since it affects the basic mathematics operations. Generally, I thought that just use the built-in operation functions e.g. `torch.add()` is a good solution.

```
OS: Mac OS X
PyTorch version: 3.0
How you installed PyTorch (conda, pip, source): conda
Python version: 3.6
CUDA/cuDNN version: None
GPU models and configuration: None
```

*---------------------------------------

I understand `dd *= 2` is multiplication in-place, but how the value of `dd` transfer into `cc`? but if I used `dd = dd * 2`, the new values did not transfer to `cc`? There is no difference in the previous line: `dd = cc` and `bb =aa`.
BTW, in python (not pytorch Variable or Tensor), `dd *= 2` and `dd = dd * 2` both will not affect `cc` value.

Comment: Something similar happens for the built-in list type: https://ideone.com/qGc9PY. So it's likely that this is the fault of the in-place mul operator, rather than anything the pytorch types are doing specifically

Comment: "*n python, dd *= 2 and dd = dd * 2 both will not affect cc value.*" - This is incorrect. Consider the identical program, but with `cc = [1,2]`.

Comment: "*the *= operator changed the original deep copy to shallow copy!*" - I think this reveals the fundmental misunderstanding. The `=` operator on "*the previous line*" does **not** copy anything. There is no copy implied by `=`, only binding a new name to an existing object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `dd = cc`, both `dd` and `cc` are now references to the same object (same for `bb = aa`). Nothing is being copied!

When you do `bb = bb * 2`, the `*` operator creates a new object and `bb` now refers to that object. No existing object is changed.

When you do `dd *= 2`, the object that `dd` refers to (and which `cc` also refers to) is changed.

So the difference is that `*` creates a new object and `=` makes a variable refer to a new object (rather than changing the object in any way), whereas `*=` changes the object.

It may be counter-intuitive that `x *= y` behaves differently than `x = x * y`, but those are the semantics of the language, not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat your tests, but additionally print the ID of your objects:

```
aa = Variable(torch.FloatTensor([[1,2],[3,4]]))
bb = aa
bb = bb*2
print(bb , id(bb))
print(aa , id(aa))

cc = Variable(torch.FloatTensor([[1,2],[3,4]]))
dd = cc
dd *= 2
print(cc, id(cc))
print(dd, id(dd))
```

This should provide you with an idea what happens.

I havent got torch, but normal lists do it similarly:

```
aa = [1,2,3,4]
bb = aa
bb = bb*2
print(bb, id(bb))
print(aa, id(aa))

cc =[1,2,3,4]
dd = cc
dd *= 2
print(cc, id(cc))
print(dd, id(dd))
```

Output for normal lists (have got no spark):

```
([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 140432043987888)  # bb  different ids
([1, 2, 3, 4], 140432043930400)              # aa  different ids  
([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 140432043916032)  # cc  same id, same object
([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 140432043916032)  # dd  same id, same object
```

Comment: try simple number instead of list, you will get different result.

Comment: @Daniel simple numbers are not mutables. Lists are mutable. That is the whole point.